# Canon EDSDK set focus point

Tags: setfocus, autofocus, edsdk, canon-sdk

I'm trying to change the focus point on the **Camera** from a `click` in a live view frame using the **EDSDK** *lib*. I can't figure out how to do it, i mean, don't know what property I must set in order to change the focus point. Do you guys have any idea or any sample?
By the way, I'm already able to change some other values like `ISO`, `AV`, `TV` or *color temperature*.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set an `EdsPoint` into `kEdsPropID_Evf_ZoomPosition` before triggering a focus command. The name "Zoom" is a bit confusing, but this property:

> *Gets/sets the focus and zoom border position for live view. The focus and zoom border is set using EdsCameraRef, but obtained using live
>   view image data, in otherwords, by using EdsEvfImageRef.*

Comment: Thanks @gdh, you made my day!

Answer (score 0):

you can set zoom point adding this method to the camera class.

```
public void SetZoomPositionSetting(PropertyID propID, Point value, int inParam = 0)
{
    CheckState();

    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Point));
    ErrorCode err = CanonSDK.EdsSetPropertyData(CamRef, propID, inParam, size, value);
}
```

and call this method like this.
    MainCamera.SetZoomPositionSetting(PropertyID.Evf_ZoomPosition, p);
p in here is EOSDigital.SDK.Point instance.

and dont forget to change camera setting to AF Live mode.(not quick mode)